# cv2 webcam stream only showing first few lines of image

Tags: python, opencv, sockets

Hey so i wrote a Python script to stream a webcam to a other device via UDP.
But when i start the stream only the first few lines of the Image get displayed.
Also even through i used the same Variable for writing the File to disk and displaying it i get diffrent results. Because in the saved image the colours are normal but in the live picture the colours are(i think) inverted.
What i already tried:

- using a lan connection between the devices
- searching on google for others with the same problem

Server code:

```
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2
import socket,json
MESSAGE = [0,0,0]
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a = 0
class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self,obj):
        if isinstance(obj,np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self,obj)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    UDP_IP = "192.168.1.147"
    UDP_PORT = 5005
    MESSAGE = json.dumps({"a" : frame[0], "b" : frame[1],"c" : frame[2]}, cls = NumpyEncoder)
    with open("test.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(MESSAGE)
        
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 16384)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                         socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode(),(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
```

Client:

```
import socket,json
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
framecounter = 0
class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
UDP_IP = "192.168.1.147"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
    json_dump, addr = sock.recvfrom(65535)
    json_load = json.loads(json_dump.decode())
    new_rgb = np.asarray(json_load["a"]),np.asarray(json_load["b"]),np.asarray(json_load["c"])
    new_rgb = np.float32(new_rgb)
    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",new_rgb)
    cv2.imshow("frame",new_rgb)
    cv2.resizeWindow("frame",(640,480))
    framecounter = framecounter + 1
    print("frame",framecounter)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: Why are you creating a TCP stream first, then UDP? Are you aware you can't send more than 64kB in a UDP message and often far less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame returned value from cap.read() is just one single image from the stream, it is a matrix of size (height, width, channels), so when you do frame[0] you are getting only the first line of this matrix.
Secondly, your encoding is inefficient, if you want to send one image (frame) at a time you could just dump the image file into the socket.

Here is my implementation, beware that as the receiver is single-threaded, it may loose several packets if it starts to do slow operations (such as writing to disk, computer vision). In that case you should create another thread that only to listens to that port and writes to a queue.

receive.py

```
import socket
import cv2
import io
import numpy as np
import traceback

DATAGRAM_SIZE = 1400 #bytes
PORT = 44000
end_bytes = bytes(17)
framecounter = 0

listening_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
listening_socket.bind(('', PORT))
while True:
    image_buffer = io.BytesIO() # faster than writing to file
    data, address = listening_socket.recvfrom(DATAGRAM_SIZE)
    while data != end_bytes:
        image_buffer.write(data)
        data, address = listening_socket.recvfrom(DATAGRAM_SIZE)
    image_buffer.seek(0)
    try: # image may be corrupted by loss of UDP packets
        img = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(bytearray(image_buffer.read()), dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow("received", img) # If the code gets slow here you may loose packets
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    framecounter += 1
    print(framecounter)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

listening_socket.close()
```

sender.py

```
import socket
import cv2
import numpy
import time

DATAGRAM_SIZE = 1400
PORT = 44000
IP = "127.0.0.1"
end_bytes = bytes(17)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
sending_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("sent",frame)
    cv2.imwrite("img_to_send.jpg",frame) # You may use BytesIO
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    with open("img_to_send.jpg", "rb") as f:
        data = f.read(DATAGRAM_SIZE)
        while data:
            sending_socket.sendto(data, (IP, PORT))
            data = f.read(DATAGRAM_SIZE)
        sending_socket.sendto(end_bytes, (IP, PORT))

sending_socket.close()
cap.release()
```